# Find matching key range for pairs

Tags: c++, dictionary

Let's say I have a map:

```
std::map<std::pair<string,int>,int> map_example;
```

How do I find all elements in my map that have a key with the following properties: The string in the pair is "A" and the int is between 5 and 10, inclusive.  Alternatively, would it instead be better to make my map as the below?

```
std::map<string,std::map<int,int> map_example2;
```

Comment: `map::lower_bound` and `map::upper_bound` might help.

Answer (score 0):

The `result` variable will give you a `map` that contains all elements from `map_example` that match you criteria:

```
decltype(map_example) result;
for (const auto& item : map_example) {
    const auto& key = item.first;
    if (key.first == "A" && key.second >= 5 && key.second <= 10)
        result.insert(item);
}
```

It iterates through the whole `map` and checks each element if it satisfies the condition, if yes, it inserts the element into the `result` `map`.

Comment: Hello thank you for trying to answer this question, can you briefly explain how your solution addresses OP's problem?